# Reactor-test: SterVerifier.expectNoEvent() is not working as expected

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to test a `Processor` serving as event bus (`EmitterProcessor` in this example).
Here's the code of a unit test:

```
val testBus = EmitterProcessor.create<Message>()
StepVerifier.create(testBus.log())
                .expectSubscription()
                .then { testBus.onNext(message1) }
                .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .thenCancel().verify(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
```

I expect my test to fail, since the event I just pushed is published to processor and is immediately received, so `expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` should trigger test failure. `log()` output confirms that event is received:

```
13:02:33.858 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onSubscribe(EmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
13:02:33.860 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - request(unbounded)
13:02:33.863 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(Message(id=1, payload=1, destination=RouterDestination(value=)))
13:02:34.865 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - cancel()
```

But my test completes successfuly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelBerry Yes, you are right! It's indeed that bug. After downgrading to 3.1.2 this code behaves as expected. Seems like a pretty serious flaw, hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: As is, it's unlikely to be fixed soon unfortunately (Simon confirmed on the Github issue it was a rather tricky one to get to the bottom of, and may require a rewrite to fix.) However, an `expectTimeoutAfter()` method has been added which should cover the core cases more succinctly.